# How do I add a counter in Stata that resets with each new ID

Tags: stata

I want to add a counter (**new_var-count-year**) to my dataset in Stata.

```
ID year new_var-count-year
 1 2000 1
 1 2001 2
 1 2002 2
 2 2001 1
 2 2002 2
 3 1999 1
 3 2000 2
 3 2001 3
 3 2002 4
 4 2005 1
 5 2000 1
 5 2001 2
```

I know this is super easy in most languages but this:

```
if ID == ID[_n+1]{
 new_var-count-year = new_var-count-year+1
 }
else ...
```

does not seem to work here.

What does work (very bad code!) is:

```
gen freq_year = 1
bysort ID (year) : gen new_var-count-year = sum(freq_year)
```

Comment: The last block of code is illegal, so please don't claim that it works. (Hyphens or dashes are not allowed in Stata variable names.)  However, `bysort ID (year) : gen wanted = sum(1)` would work too, so you don't need the other variable. But that code is equivalent to what I have already posted as an answer. Explaining why your `if` statement does not work is more interesting and I will post on that later today.  it's super-easy in Stata too!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I actually forgot about your answer and tried to find out myself by trial and error but it's certainly **not** a result I would use in my code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find your code hard to follow in detail (`x` is a value of `ID` which is given but also a variable to be produced???) but

```
bysort ID : gen wanted = _n
```

sounds like what you are asking for. Often there is some variable such as time or time order as a rationale for the ordering. If so, you should spell that out with

```
bysort ID (time) : gen wanted = _n
```

If that's not the answer, you might find that a specific example with fake data and what you want is more likely to get a solution.

EDIT on extra material added to question 27 Nov 2020:

`if` as a stand-alone statement always looks in the first observation when given variable names (unless anything else is explicit). This is explained -- although in my view backwards, as the question there asked is the answer to the more common question why don't `if` statements work as I expect? -- in [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/).

Consider this (corrected) version of your sample dataset and some experiments with it. I use `display` (`di` is accepted as an abbreviation).

```
clear 

input ID year new_var_count_year
 1 2000 1
 1 2001 2
 1 2002 2
 2 2001 1
 2 2002 2
 3 1999 1
 3 2000 2
 3 2001 3
 3 2002 4
 4 2005 1
 5 2000 1
 5 2001 2
end
```

Experiment 1: a variable name reference is evaluated in the first observation of the dataset.

```
. di ID
1
```

(For this example dataset, 1 is ambiguous output, but other experiments will confirm the point.)

Experiment 2: for the same reason a reference to `_n` is always interpreted as 1 in the same context. (Detail: `_n` by itself implies "new line" to display, so the parentheses are needed for the observation number interpretation.)

```
. di (_n) 
1
```

Experiment 3: a reference to `_n+1` is always interpreted as 2 in the same context.

```
. di (_n+1) 
2
```

Assertion: Even within a loop, the way that such expressions work is not affected.

Note also that "does not seem to work here" is imprecise: the code as given is illegal because there is no `generate` provided.

More positively, this works and is perhaps closer to what you were thinking.

```
gen wanted = 1 if ID != ID[_n-1]
replace wanted = wanted[_n-1] + 1 if missing(wanted)
```

There is always scope for an explicit loop over observations; it is just not very Stataish or efficient. It is a slow version of the two lines just given.

```
gen wanted =  . 

local n = _N 

forval i = 1/`n' { 
    if id[`i'] != id[`i' - 1] replace wanted = 1 in `i' 
    else replace wanted = wanted[`i' - 1] + 1 in `i' 
}
```

where for context note that a reference to *varname*`[0]` is always evaluated as missing.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Your update made it very clear how to use Stata.